# Unit Test for a function with got module using sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I have 2 functions,

```
const callAndParseHttp = async (url) => {
      const response = await got(url);
       return await parseXml(response.body);
};

const parseXml = async xmlData => {
      try {
            const json = parser.toJson(xmlData.body);
            return JSON.parse(json);
      } catch (err) {
            return err;
      }
 };
```

And I have wrote a unit test in sinon for that looks like,

```
describe('/ handler', () => {
    let spy;
    before(() => {
        spy = sinon.spy(unitParser, 'callAndParseHttp');
    });
afterEach(() => {
    spy.restore();
});
it('unit parser testing', async () => {
    await unitParser.callAndParseHttp(
        'http://www.mocky.io/v2/5e34242423'
    );
    expect(spy.callCount).to.equal(1);
});
})
```

Do I need to create stub for this test ? I'm new to unit testing. Tests are passing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This way you are not testing it completely. Better approach will be to mock the http call using `nock` and test the function end to end. You can see the example here

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock

The way you are testing, it doesn't really test anything as it completely replaces the function with the `spy` which you are using.

Comment: Is spy or stub is more suitable here ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LakshmipriyaMukundan i guess you don't need to use spy or stub. Just use sinon and mock the response. if you want you can use nock with spy.